# How to parse through a functions for each ng-repeat item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Ok guys so im having this problem were i have to make each date go through a functions so i get result.. lets look at the portion of code so we can understand properly:

```
 <md-list>
        <md-divider ></md-divider>
        <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">Replies</md-subheader>
        <md-list-item class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="reps in replies">
            {{reps.replyCreatorDate}}
            <ng-md-icon icon="phone" style="fill: white" size="20"></ng-md-icon>
            <img ng-src="{{reps.replyCreatorAvatar}}" class="md-avatar" alt="Something Went Wong"/>

            <div class="md-list-item-text">
                <h3> {{reps.replyCreatorUsername}} </h3>
                <p> {{reps.replyCreatorValue}} </p>
            </div>
            <md-button class="md-secondary md-icon-button" aria-label="call">
                <ng-md-icon icon="phone" style="fill: white" size="20"></ng-md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
```

Here you see reps.replyCreatorDate .... Well that gives me a date number like this:

```
1460924923708
```

Well i want that to be like '2 hours ago' or like '1 day ago'... and i already have a built in service that will do that for me... all i have to do if it was only one was this:

```
timeService.getTimeF(new Date(parseInt($scope.replyCreatorDate)))
```

But i dont know how to pass each $scope.replyCreatorDate through that funnction... so it renders correctly. Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to make a filter like this

```
app.filter("getTime", function(){
   return function(input){
      // Called Your function here
      return output; 
   }
});

<md-list-item class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="reps in replies">
            {{reps.replyCreatorDate | getTime}}
```